# LG tv app to display the list of messages

Tags: television, lg

Is there an LG tv app to display the list of messages from a text file or any other( xml...) from network or USB just like the breaking news in the tv?
The video must keep playing and the messages should pop up and repeat from the file.

I need it to display my office account informations on LG smart TV. Please reply. Thankyou.
If there aren't any such apps, please give me guidelines to build one from the sdk. I mean which components to focus more.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but anyway. I connect to my '14 LG smarttv over websockets on port 3000 and send the following as JSON after connecting:

`{"id":"0","type":"request","uri":"ssap://system.notifications/createToast","payload":{"message": "Super mega awesome."}}`

This will make it show a toast for a while.

But, first you must pair with the TV. It may be easier for you to simply use the ConnectSDK.